# Error while reading a JSON file with Python Polars

Tags: python, json, python-polars

I am trying to read a GeoJSON with Python Polars, like this:

```
import polars as pl
myfile = '{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Linestring","coordinates":[[10,11.2],[10.5,11.9]]},{"type":"Point","coordinates":[10,20]}]}'
pl.read_json(myfile)
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\polars\functions.py", line 631, in read_json    return DataFrame.read_json(source)  # type: ignore
  File "...\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\polars\frame.py", line 346, in read_json    
    self._df = PyDataFrame.read_json(file)
RuntimeError: Other("Error(\"missing field `columns`\", line: 1, column: 143)")
```

I have also tried to put the same content into a file and I had a similar error.

As suggested [in GitHub](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/775), I tried to read the file via Pandas, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
initial_df = pl.from_pandas(pd.read_json(file_path))
```

The error I get is:

```
File "...\file_splitter.py", line 13, in split_file
    initial_df = pl.from_pandas(pd.read_json(file_path))
  File "...\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\polars\functions.py", line 566, in from_pandas
    data[name] = _from_pandas_helper(s)
  File "...\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\polars\functions.py", line 534, in _from_pandas_helper
    return pa.array(a)
  File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 302, in pyarrow.lib.array
  File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 83, in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 97, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: cannot mix list and non-list, non-null values
```

What can I do to read the GeoJSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the file with pandas you get columsn of type `Object` where one is not known to `Arrow` (it could be anything).

If we cast the columns to type string we know that arrow and polars can deal with it.

```py
myfile = '{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Linestring","coordinates":[[10,11.2],[10.5,11.9]]},{"type":"Point","coordinates":[10,20]}]}'
print(pl.from_pandas(pd.read_json(myfile).astype(str)))
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ type               ┆ geometries                          │
│ ---                ┆ ---                                 │
│ str                ┆ str                                 │
╞════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ GeometryCollection ┆ {'type': 'Linestring', 'coordina... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ GeometryCollection ┆ {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates':... │
└────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you! The solution works! I had to install pyarrow too, via `pip install pyarrow`, to make it work.

Comment: Yes pyarrow is an optional dependency for polars. You can install it with `pip install polars[pyarrow]`